# Triplet embedded layer with custom (None) loss on Keras 2

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I've been looking for simple implementations of triplet embedding in deep learning. I wanted to use Keras as it is what I am slightly more familiar (although still very inexperienced in it).

Here is a reference on one of the inspiration works: [paper on embedded triplets](https://hpi.de/fileadmin/user_upload/fachgebiete/meinel/tele-task/papers/isvc16_Hannes.pdf)

I've found a pretty good example to start off with, working with the mnist dataset, as far as I can tell it is working pretty well. Problems arise on the implementation of the merge of the 3 embedded layers.

```
def build_model(input_shape):

base_input = Input(input_shape)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(base_input)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(2, activation='linear')(x)
embedding_model = Model(base_input, x, name='embedding')

anchor_input = Input(input_shape, name='anchor_input')
positive_input = Input(input_shape, name='positive_input')
negative_input = Input(input_shape, name='negative_input')

anchor_embedding = embedding_model(anchor_input)
positive_embedding = embedding_model(positive_input)
negative_embedding = embedding_model(negative_input)

inputs = [anchor_input, positive_input, negative_input]
outputs = [anchor_embedding, positive_embedding, negative_embedding]
triplet_model = Model(inputs, outputs)
triplet_model.add_loss(K.mean(triplet_loss(outputs)))
triplet_model.compile(loss=None, optimizer='adam') # <-- CRITICAL LINE

return embedding_model, triplet_model
```

With the currently implementation the loss is added through `model.add_loss` and I haven't find many examples like this. **The real issue though, is that I cannot load the saved model.** The lines

```
triplet_model.save('triplet.h5')
model = load_model('triplet.h5')
```

return:

```
ValueError: The model cannot be compiled because it has no loss to optimize.
```

Adding a parameter to the 'loss' argument raises another error when I try to compile the model. **I wanted to ask how can I circumvent this issue or if there is a better way to create the model with the embedded models (without the empty loss function, maybe).**

Here is the triplet_loss function for reference:

```
def triplet_loss(inputs, dist='sqeuclidean', margin='maxplus'):
    anchor, positive, negative = inputs
    positive_distance = K.square(anchor - positive)
    negative_distance = K.square(anchor - negative)
    if dist == 'euclidean':
        positive_distance = K.sqrt(K.sum(positive_distance, axis=-1, keepdims=True))
        negative_distance = K.sqrt(K.sum(negative_distance, axis=-1, keepdims=True))
    elif dist == 'sqeuclidean':
        positive_distance = K.mean(positive_distance, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        negative_distance = K.mean(negative_distance, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    loss = positive_distance - negative_distance
    if margin == 'maxplus':
        loss = K.maximum(0.0, 1 + loss)
    elif margin == 'softplus':
        loss = K.log(1 + K.exp(loss))
    return K.mean(loss)
```

Here is the full script: [link](https://pastebin.com/TaGFdcBA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you leave `triplet_model.compile(loss=None)`, but `keras` does not know how to deal with it properly in `load_model()`. I understand that you have to do so, but you can load the model in a different way to solve your current issue.

In short, don't load the entire model through `load_model()`, but just the weights through `load_weights()`.

For example, you can do

```
# save only weights
triplet_model.save_weights('tmp.h5') 
# load saved weights
new_embedding_model, new_triplet_model = build_model(input_shape)
new_triplet_model.load_weights('tmp.h5') # load only weights
```

Comment: This worked! Mate, thank you very much, I am training on harder datasets than mnist and having saved states is really important.